# how to avoid the calling a function with a null in php

Tags: php

I have an html form contains some inputs. In my PHP function I have some conditions and depended if some inputs are set on or not I call the right function. Here is the example :

```
if($a)
   //Call the function 1
elseif($a == 0)
   //Call the function2

 if($b)
   //Call the function 1
elseif($b == 0)
   //Call the function2
```

So i have two HTML inputs when one of them is setted i call the right function. The problem is when one of them is empty it's still calls the function and in the condition i set `== 0 and not !$a`per example. So someone can help me please Thanks.

Comment: unclear - when which is empty, which function is being called?

Comment: is the case of all the inputs when they are empty is still call the functions in the `== 0` condition.

Comment: show the actual code please

Answer (score 2):

Check this out
[How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

You may want to compare using `===` for the typesafe comparison between the input and the number 0

Comment: I solved the problem. I have to set "0" and not 0. Thanks